# Oozie Coordinator - custom EL functions

Tags: hadoop, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I need to create a custom EL function and use it in uri-template (an equivalent of YEAR, MONTH).
It is possible? What is the key configuration to put in `oozie-site.xml` for this area of coordinator?

Comment: Welcome to SO ! in order to get the best from your question, please provide as much details as possible. In this case please add the workflow.xml and coordinator.xml and a bit more of the error you reviced

Comment: Hi @Mzf , thanks for your reply.
I reformulated my qyestion

Answer (score 0):

The property `oozie.service.ELService.ext.functions.workflow` is the one where you have to include all maps of the extended EL function to the associated class and method. Multiple map entries are separated by commas.

```
<property>
<name>oozie.service.ELService.ext.functions.workflow</name>
<value>
yourELkey=fully_quallified_class_name#static_method_name
</value>
<description>
EL functions declarations, separated by commas, format is
[PREFIX:]NAME=CLASS#METHOD. This property is a convenience
property to add extensions to the built in executors without
having to include all the built in ones.
</description>
</property>
```

For further info on how to package and deploy you can refer to [this](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/09/how-to-write-an-el-function-in-apache-oozie/).

EDIT: Since you are interested in EL functions for co-ordinator similar to YEAR, MONTH  you can take a look at below property ( documented in oozie-default.xml and you will need to add it to oozie-site.xml as former is only documentation) - `oozie.service.ELService.functions.coord-job-submit-freq`
and `oozie.service.ELService.ext.functions.coord-job-submit-freq`.

```
<property>
        <name>oozie.service.ELService.functions.coord-job-submit-freq</name>
        <value>
            coord:days=org.apache.oozie.coord.CoordELFunctions#ph1_coord_days,
            coord:months=org.apache.oozie.coord.CoordELFunctions#ph1_coord_months,
            coord:hours=org.apache.oozie.coord.CoordELFunctions#ph1_coord_hours,
            coord:minutes=org.apache.oozie.coord.CoordELFunctions#ph1_coord_minutes,
            coord:endOfDays=org.apache.oozie.coord.CoordELFunctions#ph1_coord_endOfDays,
            coord:endOfMonths=org.apache.oozie.coord.CoordELFunctions#ph1_coord_endOfMonths,
            coord:conf=org.apache.oozie.coord.CoordELFunctions#coord_conf,
            coord:user=org.apache.oozie.coord.CoordELFunctions#coord_user,
            hadoop:conf=org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.HadoopELFunctions#hadoop_conf
        </value>
        <description>
            EL functions declarations, separated by commas, format is [PREFIX:]NAME=CLASS#METHOD.
        </description>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>oozie.service.ELService.ext.functions.coord-job-submit-freq</name>
        <value>
        </value>
        <description>
            EL functions declarations, separated by commas, format is [PREFIX:]NAME=CLASS#METHOD.
            This property is a convenience property to add extensions to the built in executors without having to
            include all the built in ones.
        </description>
    </property>
```

Comment: Thanks @Shailendra!  I already read the tutorial, and I was able to use the custom function inside a workflow, but inside a coordinator it doesn't work. I think that the property `oozie.service.ELService.ext.functions.workflow` can be used only in workflows

Comment: @Shailendra please see this question also
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47622084/oozie-custom-el-function-oozie-for-coordinator