# Oozie Custom EL function oozie for coordinator

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator

I want to create a custom el function that i will use inside oozie  coordinator. My  custom el function is working fine but when i pass already defined oozie el function as a parameter to my el function it  throws exception.

**coordinator.xml**

**${coord:dateToEpoch(coord:nominalTime(),  "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mmZ") see below example**

```
<datasets>
    <dataset name="input1" frequency="${inputDataSetFrequence}" initial-instance="${initialInstance}"
             timezone="${timezone}">
        <uri-template>${inputBasePath}/${useCaseName}/bintime=${coord:dateToEpoch(coord:nominalTime(),  "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mmZ")}
        </uri-template>
        <done-flag></done-flag>
    </dataset>
</datasets>
<input-events>
    <data-in name="coordInput1" dataset="input1">
        <instance>${coord:current(0)}</instance>
    </data-in>
</input-events>
```

Configuarion that i used to test this

```
<property>
<name>oozie.service.ELService.ext.functions.coord-job-submit-nofuncs</name>
<value>coord:dateToEpoch=com.mobileum.oozie.MobileumELFunctions#dateToEpoch</value>
</property>
```

constant param is working but dynamic param is not working

**Working call**

${coord:dateToEpoch("2009-01-01T08:00UTC", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mmZ")

**Exception call**

${coord:dateToEpoch(coord:nominalTime(), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mmZ")

**Tried to use all these properties**

```
    <property>
<name>oozie.service.ELService.ext.functions.job-submit</name>
<value>coord:dateToEpoch=com.mobileum.oozie.MobileumELFunctions#dateToEpoch</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>oozie.service.ELService.ext.functions.workflow</name>
<value>coord:dateToEpoch=com.mobileum.oozie.MobileumELFunctions#dateToEpoch</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>oozie.service.ELService.ext.functions.wf-sla-submit</name>
<value>coord:dateToEpoch=com.mobileum.oozie.MobileumELFunctions#dateToEpoch</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>oozie.service.ELService.ext.functions.coord-job-submit-freq</name>
<value>coord:dateToEpoch=com.mobileum.oozie.MobileumELFunctions#dateToEpoch</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>oozie.service.ELService.ext.functions.coord-job-submit-data</name>
<value>coord:dateToEpoch=com.mobileum.oozie.MobileumELFunctions#dateToEpoch</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>oozie.service.ELService.ext.functions.coord-job-submit-instances</name>
<value>coord:dateToEpoch=com.mobileum.oozie.MobileumELFunctions#dateToEpoch</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>oozie.service.ELService.ext.functions.coord-sla-create</name>
<value>coord:dateToEpoch=com.mobileum.oozie.MobileumELFunctions#dateToEpoch</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>oozie.service.ELService.ext.functions.coord-sla-submit</name>
<value>coord:dateToEpoch=com.mobileum.oozie.MobileumELFunctions#dateToEpoch</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>oozie.service.ELService.ext.functions.coord-action-create</name>
<value>coord:dateToEpoch=com.mobileum.oozie.MobileumELFunctions#dateToEpoch</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>oozie.service.ELService.ext.functions.coord-action-create-inst</name>
<value>coord:dateToEpoch=com.mobileum.oozie.MobileumELFunctions#dateToEpoch</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>oozie.service.ELService.ext.functions.coord-action-start</name>
<value>coord:dateToEpoch=com.mobileum.oozie.MobileumELFunctions#dateToEpoch</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>oozie.service.ELService.ext.functions.coord-job-wait-timeout</name>
<value>coord:dateToEpoch=com.mobileum.oozie.MobileumELFunctions#dateToEpoch</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>oozie.service.ELService.ext.functions.bundle-submit</name>
<value>coord:dateToEpoch=com.mobileum.oozie.MobileumELFunctions#dateToEpoch</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>oozie.service.ELService.ext.functions.coord-job-submit-initial-instance</name>
<value>coord:dateToEpoch=com.mobileum.oozie.MobileumELFunctions#dateToEpoch</value>
</property>
```

and

```
<property>
<name>oozie.service.ELService.ext.functions.coord-job-submit-nofuncs</name>
<value>coord:dateToEpoch=com.mobileum.oozie.MobileumELFunctions#dateToEpoch</value>
</property>
```

**EXCEPTION**

```
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Unable to evaluate :${inputBasePath}/${useCaseName}/bintime=${coord:dateToEpoch(coord:nominalTime(),  "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mmZ")}:

    at org.apache.oozie.coord.CoordELFunctions.evalAndWrap(CoordELFunctions.java:743)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.coord.CoordSubmitXCommand.resolveTagContents(CoordSubmitXCommand.java:1002)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: javax.servlet.jsp.el.ELException: No function is mapped to the name "coord:nominalTime"
    at org.apache.commons.el.Logger.logError(Logger.java:481)
    at org.apache.commons.el.Logger.logError(Logger.java:498)
    at org.apache.commons.el.Logger.logError(Logger.java:525)
    at org.apache.commons.el.FunctionInvocation.evaluate(FunctionInvocation.java:150)
    at org.apache.commons.el.FunctionInvocation.evaluate(FunctionInvocation.java:163)
    at org.apache.commons.el.ExpressionString.evaluate(ExpressionString.java:114)
    at org.apache.commons.el.ExpressionEvaluatorImpl.evaluate(ExpressionEvaluatorImpl.java:274)
    at org.apache.commons.el.ExpressionEvaluatorImpl.evaluate(ExpressionEvaluatorImpl.java:190)
    at org.apache.oozie.util.ELEvaluator.evaluate(ELEvaluator.java:204)
    at org.apache.oozie.coord.CoordELFunctions.evalAndWrap(CoordELFunctions.java:734)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all `Oozie` EL constructs are evaluated in `uri-template`. Please refer section [Synchronous Datasets](http://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/CoordinatorFunctionalSpec.html#a5._Dataset) for more details. Below is excerpt on `uri-template`:

> uri-template: The URI template that identifies the dataset and can be
>   resolved into concrete URIs to identify a particular dataset instance.
>   The URI template is constructed using:
>
> constants: See the allowable EL Time Constants below. Ex: ${YEAR}/${MONTH}.
>
> variables: Variables must be resolved at the time a coordinator job is submitted to the coordinator engine. They are normally provided a job parameters (configuration properties). Ex: ${market}/${language}

The following EL constants can be used within synchronous dataset URI templates:

- YEAR
- MONTH
- DAY
- HOUR
- MINUTE

Problem is not associated with your custom EL function implementation. So even if you have used following, it will not work:

```
<uri-template>${inputBasePath}/${useCaseName}/bintime=${coord:nominalTime()}</uri-template>
```